# Core web vitals results consistency problem, even all URL's are in good ( LCP | CLS )

Tags: pagespeed, google-search-console, google-pagespeed, pagespeed-insights, core-web-vitals

**1.** In Core Web Vitals, Does the Google search console rely on traffic to show the results of LCP and CLS? If yes then how much minimum traffic is required? Because In the live page insight tool there are all URLs are in good condition.

**LCP is : Under 2.5 | CLS is : Under 0.1**

**2.** Does Google search console/core web vitals results depend on CruX for each device OR page insight tool?

**3.** All the pages have CLS less than **0.01** but when the Google search console makes URL Group average it shows **0.23 CLS**. As I have checked all the sample URLs given in the group are also good. is there any way to check how it got calculated?
[image][image]

**4.** Sometimes in the search console my web vitals URLs count goes to **0** on the desktop. Does anyone know about this thing?
[image]

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you might be conflating the Chrome UX Report data from real users at the top of the page with the Lighthouse data from lab tests at the bottom. Core Web Vitals are assessed using real-user data from the Chrome UX Report.

In your first screenshot, it shows a CLS value of 0.22. This means 75% of desktop users on the page have a CLS of at or below 0.22, which is in the "Needs Improvement" category. Search Console is saying that the average experience over all pages in the group is a CLS value of 0.23, which is very similar to this particular page's performance.

The CLS value of 0.001 is based on a Lighthouse test. Importantly, Lighthouse doesn't interact with the page as a real user would, so it doesn't encounter types of CLS that may be caused by scrolling or clicking. Think of this value more as a lower bound for CLS than your page's actual user-perceived performance. That's also why Core Web Vitals are not assessed using data from Lighthouse.